# CakePHP - sort results array individually

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, cakephp

Using CakePHP 2.7, I have an array of find results:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Foo' => array(
            'id' => '786',
            'bar_id' => '12',
            // more data
        ),
        'Bar' => array(
            'id' => '12',
            // more data
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Foo' => array(
            'id' => '785',
            'bar_id' => '13',
            // more data
        ),
        'Bar' => array(
            'id' => '13',
            // more data
        )
    ),
    // many more results
```

Now I want do have it sorted by 'bar_id' in a defined *individual* way, **not numeric**. The sort order is described in another array:

```
array(9, 3, 18, 36, …)
```

Is there a better way to do it but to loop over the sort array, pick the current id then loop over the results array (a loop within a loop), look there for the corresponding 'bar_id' and if found write the result into a new results array?

```
$results = array(…); // the results
$order = array(9, 3, 18, 36, …);
$sortedResults = array();
foreach ($order as $barId) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($barId == $result['Foo']['bar_id']) {
            $sortedResults[] = $result;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that Cake has the Hash utility (formerly 'Set') to work with arrays, but I couldn't find a way to do it with Has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this way:

```
$indexed_results = Hash::combine($results , '{n}.Foo.bar_id', '{n}');

foreach($order as $index)
{
    $sortedResults[] = $indexed_results[$index];
}
```

the first row replaces the index in `$results` with the corrispondant value of `bar_id` so you can do a single loop

**edit:** probably you'll have to check that the `$index` actually exists in your array unless you're sure that every value in `$order` has a correspondent `bar_id` otherwise you'll get a "Undefined index" notice

Comment: Thank you, arilia. It works just fine! I'm sorry, my reputation is not high enough to vote up your answer.